# Detours 3.0 application crashing when hooking SetRect

Tags: c++, dll, hook, code-injection, detours

I am trying to hook [SetRect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145085(v=vs.85).aspx) function using Detours but my program is crashing directly after hooking. I tried hooking other functions such as [DrawText](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162498(v=vs.85).aspx) before and everything worked fine and now I am not sure if there is a problem with my code or there is something about SetRect (and other similar functions) that I am not aware of causing the crash.

For testing I am using the provided Detours run with dll program:

```
withdll.exe -d:mydll.exe simpleprogram.exe
```

Where simpleprogram.exe is a simple one button C# application. Tried testing also on notepad, calc, firefox but all of them crashed too.

My hook DLL

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <detours.h>
#include<string>
#include<fstream>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

wofstream out;

BOOL(__stdcall * T14)
(
_Out_ LPRECT lprc,
_In_  int    xLeft,
_In_  int    yTop,
_In_  int    xRight,
_In_  int    yBottom

) = SetRect;


__declspec(dllexport) BOOL  M14
(
_Out_ LPRECT lprc,
_In_  int    L,
_In_  int    T,
_In_  int    R,
_In_  int    B
){

    out << "SetRect: " << L << " " << T << " " << R << " " << B << endl;
    return T14(lprc, L, T, R, B);
}

BOOL WINAPI DllMain(HINSTANCE hinst, DWORD dwReason, LPVOID reserved)
{
    if (dwReason == DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH)
    {
        out.open("out.txt");
        out << "Attached" << endl;
        DetourRestoreAfterWith();
        DetourTransactionBegin();
        DetourUpdateThread(GetCurrentThread());
        DetourAttach(&(PVOID&)T14, M14);
        DetourTransactionCommit();
    }
    else if (dwReason == DLL_PROCESS_DETACH)
    {
        out << "detached" << endl;
        out.close();
        DetourTransactionBegin();
        DetourUpdateThread(GetCurrentThread());
        DetourDetach(&(PVOID&)T14, M14);
        DetourTransactionCommit();
    }

    return TRUE;
}
```

The output I am getting:

> Attached
>
> SetRect: 138 161 323 161

So the program is crashing after the first SetRect function is called, any ideas why this is happening ?

Comment: Does `DetourTransactionCommit() == NO_ERROR`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your detoured function's calling convention is wrong.

Visual C++ projects default to `__cdecl`, but ALL of the Windows API uses `WINAPI` (`__stdcall`).

You are trashing the callstack due to differences in calling convention. This issue does not exist in 64-bit software since there is only one calling convention, but for x86 it is critically important that you match any calling convention defined in the original function's prototype.

---

```
__declspec(dllexport) BOOL WINAPI M14
(
_Out_ LPRECT lprc,
_In_  int    L,
_In_  int    T,
_In_  int    R,
_In_  int    B
){

    out << "SetRect: " << L << " " << T << " " << R << " " << B << endl;
    return T14(lprc, L, T, R, B);
}
```

---

On another, possibly even more serious and difficult to debug note. I would refrain from doing C++ stream I/O in `DllMain (...)`. Unless you statically linked your DLL to the MSVCRT this brings in dependencies on other DLLs while you are holding the loader lock.

You can wind up deadlocking if you call any function from DllMain that is not statically linked or part of `kernel32.dll` or `user32.dll`. The good news is kernel32 and user32 have a plethora of string functions -- enough that you should not even need the C++ standard library ;)

Comment: Adding the WINAPI fixed it thanks ! 

Also thanks for the note, I am always testing my program without any C++ I/O to rule out this possibility whenever I get an error.

Answer (score 1):

I just tried hooking `SetRect()`, and I got it to hook correctly on Calc. I'll put the code I used below for the DLL.

```
    static BOOL (WINAPI *TrueSetRect)(LPRECT, int, int, int, int) = SetRect;
    ...
    ...
    BOOL WINAPI __stdcall MySetRect(LPRECT lprc, int L, int T, int R, int B)
    {
        printf("MySetRect: L = %i; T = %i; R = %i; B = %i", L, T, R, B);
        return TrueSetRect(lprc, L, T, R, B);
    }

    __declspec(dllexport)
    BOOL WINAPI DllMain(HINSTANCE hinstDLL, DWORD fdwReason, LPVOID lpvReserved)
    {
        if(fdwReason == DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH)
        {
             DetourTransactionBegin();
             DetourUpdateThread(GetCurrentThread());
             DetourAttach( &reinterpret_cast<PVOID&>(TrueSetRect), MySetRect);
             if(DetourTransactionCommit() == NO_ERROR)
             {
                 //Detour successful
             }
        }
        if(fdwReason == DLL_PROCESS_DETACH)
        {
            DetourTransactionBegin();
            DetourUpdateThread(GetCurrentThread());
            DetourDetach( &reinterpret_cast<PVOID&>(TrueSetRect), MySetRect);
            if(DetourTransactionCommit() != NO_ERROR)
            {
                //Detach unsuccessful
            } else {
                //Detach successful
            }
         }
     }
```

I suspect that it might be the way you are instantiating `SetRect()` and `YourSetRect()`, because that is the only thing different between my code and yours.

Comment: The issue was a mistake in my calling convention as Andon noted. Thanks